# Which precision is used for intermediate results of integer operation in C language?

Tags: c, typedef

Let's say I have the following variables and the following equation:

```
int16_t a,b,c,d;
int32_t result;

result = a*b - c*d;
```

The intermediate results of a*b and c*d will be stored in 16 bits or in 32 bits?

PS: I can test this faster than I can write the question, I want to know what does the C specification say.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570 *6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers, 2
The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
be used: — An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.[...] If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.*

Comment: Also, you claim the ability to test this. I posit that you *can't* test this, because the range of values `int` and `unsigned int` can represent is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EOF The main reason of which I put the question. I could have tested but I was concerned if it would be cross-platform consistent. I just wanted to avoid an answer like yes or no based on someone else just testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I will be updating this answer soon. I no longer believe that the standard permits `int16_t` to be promoted to `long`. But it can, in some extremely obscure cases, promote to `unsigned int`. The integer conversion rank rules have some odd results for exotic systems.***

[chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36212898/827263) is *practically* correct. There are a couple of obscure and unlikely cases where the intermediate result is of type `long int`.

`int16_t` is required to be a 16-bit 2's-complement integer type with no padding bits. Operands of type `int16_t` will be promoted to a type that can represent all possible values of type `int16_t` and that is at least as wide as `int`.

The standard requires `int` to have a range of at least -32767 to +32767.

Suppose `int` is represented using 1's-complement or sign-and-magnitude *or* that it's represented using 2's-complement but the representation that would normally be `-32768` is treated as a trap representation. Then `int` *cannot* hold all values of type `int16_t`, and the operands must be promoted to `long` (which is guaranteed to have a wide enough range).

For this to happen, the implementation would have to support *both* an `int` type with a restricted 16-bit range (most likely not 2's-complement) *and* a type that's suitable for `int16_t`, meaning it has a 2's-complement representation and no padding bits or trap representations. A 1's-complement system, for example, would be more likely not to have such a type, and so it would not define `int16_t` at all (though it would define `int_fast16_t` and `int_least16_t`).

For practically all real-world implementations, `int` can hold all values of type `int16_t`, so the intermediate results are of type `int`.  For practically all *remaining* real-world or hypothetical systems, `int16_t` would not be provided. For the hypothetical tiny fraction of nonexisting but conforming C implementations, the intermediate results are of type `long int`.

**UPDATE :** chux points out a possible weakness in my argument. In a comment, he argues that [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.6.2 paragraph 2, which says that integer types may be represented using either two's complement, ones' complement, or sign and magnitude, is intended to require that all integer types use the same representation (differing in number of bits, of course, but all using the same one of those there choices).

The phrasing of the non-normative text in J.3.5, saying that:

> Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude,
>   two’s complement, or ones’ complement, and whether the extraordinary
>   value is a trap representation or an ordinary value

is implementation-defined, tends to support that in interpretation. If different integer types can differ in that respect, it should say that *for each integer type*.

However:

1. 6.2.6.2p2 doesn't *explicitly* say that all integer types must use the same representation, and I'm not aware of anything else that implies that they must do so.
2. It could be useful to support integer types with different representations. For example, the hardware might support ones' complement, but the implementation might support two's complement integers in software for the sake of code that depends on `int16_t` et al. Or the hardware might directly support both representations. (My guess is that the authors didn't consider this possibility, but we can only go by what the standard actually says.)
3. In any case, it's not actually necessary to invoke non-two's-complement representations to construct a case where `int16_t` promotes to `long int`.

Assume the following:

- All integer types use two's complement representation.
- `INT_MAX == +32767`
- `INT_MIN == -32767`
- An `int` with sign bit 1 and all value bits 0 is a trap representation.

`int` has no padding bits, but the bit pattern that would normally represent `-32768` is a trap representation. This is explicitly permitted by N1570 6.2.6.2 paragraph 2.

But the range of `int16_t` *must* be `-32768` to `+32767`. 7.20.2.1 says that `INTN_MIN` is required to be exactly -(2<sup>N-1</sup>) (`N==16` in this case).

So under this **almost entirely implausible** but conforming implementation, `int16_t` is defined, but `int` cannot represent all values of `int16_t`, so `int16_t` values are promoted to `long int` (which must be at least 32 bits).

Comment: Concerning `int16_t` and "Suppose `int` is represented using 1's-complement", see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212843/which-precision-is-used-for-intermediate-results-of-integer-operation-in-c-langu/36212898?noredirect=1#comment60059001_36212898)

Comment: A type that cannot be implicitly converted to `int` per *6.3.1.1* is not converted to `long`, even if `long` *can* represent all values of the type.

Comment: There is never promotion to `long` in C. Also there is no implicit conversion to `long` in any possible circumstance in OP's code. (Other than the final assignment to `result` obviously).

Comment: In this situation (`int` 16-bit non 2's complement, `int16_t` a typedef for an extended integer type), the *integer conversion rank* rules (6.3.1.1/1)  "The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width." says that `int` has higher rank than `int16_t`.  Then the *integer promotion* rules (6.3.1.1/2) say that `int16_t` is promoted to `unsigned int`. (because `int` cannot represent all values).

Comment: The integer conversion rank rules seem to contain a contradiction in some cases. e.g. if we have `int` 32-bit but only with 30 value bits used; and `int32_t` an extended integer type, then the rule I quoted above says that `int` has higher rank, but the rule "The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer
type with less precision." says that `int32_t` has higher rank.

Comment: In [almost entirely implausible world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizarro_World)  `int16_t` is either of lesser or greater rank than `int/union`.  If of lesser rank, it is converted to `int/unsigned` per _integer promotion_ §6.3.1.1 2.  If `int16_t` is of greater rank, than  `int` then _usual arithmetic conversions_ §6.3.1.8,  and the operands are all `int16_t` and "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed." applies.  As@M.M commented above, there is no path to `long`.

Comment: @chux: Hmm. I'll have to take a close look at the wording on conversion ranks.

Comment: @M.M: Rank is determined in part by *width*, which is the number of value and sign bits. If `int` has 30 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 1 padding bit, then `int32_t` has higher rank than `int`. "The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer
type with less precision." (*Precision* is the number of value bits.)

Comment: @chux: Integer conversion ranks lead to some odd conclusions. If `int` has a range of -32767..+32767 and `int16_t` is an extended integer type, then `int16_t` still has a lower integer conversion rank than `int`, even though it has a wider range. A value of type `int16_t` is converted by the *integer promotions*, to `unsigned int`, since `int` can't hold all the values. I doubt that this was the intent.

Comment: Still assert "so `int16_t` values are promoted to `long int`" is valid?

Comment: @chux: Still unsure of my conclusions, and haven't updated my answer yet. Do you agree that the Standard's wording implies the `uint16_t` values can be promoted to `unsigned ` on a bizarre implementation?

Comment: `int16_t` will get promoted to `int/unsigned` or remain `int16_t`.  There are no other options.  Certainly we agree `int` is a reasonable/popular result.  All that is left is to determine if `int16_t` would ever become `unsigned ` or remain `int16_t`.  In order for that, `int16_t` must be ranked higher than at least `int`.

Comment: ... IMO, that is an untenable/unrealistic machine - it would never be built and does not exist.  I can envision a machine with some  variant integer types using 2's with 1's and/or S/M.  Yet on such a machine, certainly `int` would the the 2's form of integer and the 1's and S/M be the lower ranked types.  So in the end: Yes on a bizarre machine, yet effectively no as code does not need to work on such

Comment: @chux: The nonexistent machine I'm thinking of would have 1's-c or s/m in hardware, with 2's-c implemented less efficiently in software. Given that, I think it would make sense to make `int` 1's-c and use an extended 2's-c type for `uint16_t`. I'll update my answer later today.

Comment: `uint16_t` or `int16_t`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107559/discussion-between-chux-and-keith-thompson).

Answer (score 4):

The intermediate results will be of type `int`.

Any type narrower than `int`, will first be promoted. These *integer promotions* are to types `int` or `unsigned` **.  Math therefore *must* occur at either `int`, `unsigned` or the original type.

`int16_t` is certainly narrower or the same as `int`.

The type of `result` is irrelevant to the type of the intermediate results

```
int16_t a,b,c,d;
int32_t result = a*b - c*d;
```

To make portable for all platforms, including those with a `int` narrower that `int32_t`, insure the products are calculated using at least 32-bit math.

```
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t result = INT32_C(1)*a*b - INT32_C(1)*c*d;
```

---

Of course the result is store as 32-bit, possible sign extending the `int` intermediate results.

With machines with 32 or 64-bit `int`, the intermediate results would fit in `int32_t` with no change in value with no exception.  Results are `-2147450880 to 2147450880`  (80008000 to 7FFF8000).

** Never `long`, not even on [unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendary_creature) platforms.

Comment: What if `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT == 16`?

Comment: @EOF then `int16_t` is almost certainly a typedef for `int`

Comment: @EOF `int16_t` will be promoted to `int`, in that case.  Same range, different type.

Comment: What if `int` uses signed-magnitude or ones' complement representation, while `int16_t` uses two's complement (as it has to)?

Comment: @EOF Conjecture-able if 16-bit `int16_t` is allowed with 16-bit non-2's compliment `int`.  Hmmmm

Comment: @chux: The numerical limits given in C11 draft standard n1570 *5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>*  make this permissible: `INT_MIN -32767`

Comment: @chux it's allowed, although I doubt any such implementation ever existed

Comment: Thus that means that if the architecture is 16-bit the intermediate results will be stored in 16-bit, right? Or equivalently saying, if the types described above were instead int32_t and int64_t, respectively, and the architecture was 32 bits I would risk overflow.

Comment: @M.M The C spec also says "For signed integer types ... If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in **one** of the following ways:.. (the 3 ways) " C11 §6.2.6.2 2.  My take on this is that the only 1 method is allowed and since we have `int16_t`, then signed integer types are _two’s complement_.  This by itself may make an interesting post.

Comment: @chux: See my answer.

Comment: @chux: Interesting point about the "one of the following ways". But the same section also says "There shall be exactly one sign bit". *That* obviously can't be the same for all signed types...

Comment: @gabrieldiego Detail: `-32768  *  -32768 + -32768  *  -32768` --> `2147483648`, which is 32-bit `int` overflow --> UB.  Oops my bad, you have a minus - will re-think.

Comment: @chux: There is no addition in the expression, only subtraction and multiplication.

Comment: @gabrieldiego Re-calculation with `a*b - c*d` does not lead to any `int` overflow when `int` is 32-bit.

Comment: @chux: "*Never `long`, not even on unicorn platforms.*" -- Please see my updated answer.